# How can I declare the $default catch-all route using CDK for an API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Within the AWS console, it is possible to add a route to an API Gateway with the value of `$default`. This then removes the ability to input a HTTP method for the route.

The AWS console describes it as:
"You can also specify one $default route per API. The $default route is invoked when the request to the API matches no other routes."

I am trying to recreate this using AWS CDK v2 (C# in this case) however am having no luck.
I integrate my API Gateway with a Lambda function based on an image stored in ECR, unfortunately I cannot get my API Gateway to be created with the `$default` route.

```
httpApi.AddRoutes(new AddRoutesOptions()
{
   Path = "$default",
   Integration = lambdaProxyIntegration
});
```

Doing the above, defaults the HTTP method to POST.
It is also possible to specify a HTTP method like so:

```
httpApi.AddRoutes(new AddRoutesOptions()
{
   Path = "$default",
   Integration = lambdaProxyIntegration,
   Methods = new [] {HttpMethod.ANY}
});
```

But there is no option equivalent to when you enter `$default` within the AWS console & it greys out the drop down to select a Http Method.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem.

So confusingly, despite the `$default` catch-all route, being a route. You don't actually specify it using the `AddRoutes()` method. The clue is in the fact that it takes an enum called `HttpMethod`.

Instead, a `$default` route is applied automatically when you set the `DefaultIntegration` attribute on the `HttpApiProps` object of your `HttpApi`.

So in my case, `httpApi` from the examples in the question were an instance of the `HttpApi` class.

```
var httpApi = new HttpApi(this, Constants.API_GATEWAY_ID, new HttpApiProps()
{
   ApiName = "Your API name",
   CreateDefaultStage = true,
   DefaultIntegration = lambdaProxyIntegration
});
```

Once you specify the `DefaultIntegration`, AWS will set the `$default` route as expected.